# FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point when solving NONLINEAR EQUATIONS

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

I have tried many methods to solve the following nonlinear equations.

```
equa={AmI[1] CmI[1] - (BmI[1] CmI[1])/R3^2 == k1 u0, 
 2 R3 AmI[2] CmI[2] - (2 BmI[2] CmI[2])/R3^3 == 0, 
 AmI[1] DmI[1] - (BmI[1] DmI[1])/R3^2 == 0, 
 2 R3 AmI[2] DmI[2] - (2 BmI[2] DmI[2])/R3^3 == 0, 
 AmI[1] CmI[1] - (BmI[1] CmI[1])/R2^2 == 
  R2^(-1 - (
    2 \[Pi])/\[Beta]) \[Beta] (-((
      2 Aki[2] (Sin[thetai] - Sin[thetai + \[Beta]]))/(
      4 \[Pi]^2 - \[Beta]^2)) + (
     2 R1^(-((4 \[Pi])/\[Beta])) R2^((4 \[Pi])/\[Beta])
       Aki[2] (Sin[thetai] - Sin[thetai + \[Beta]]))/(
     4 \[Pi]^2 - \[Beta]^2) - (
     R2^(\[Pi]/\[Beta])
       Aki[1] (Sin[thetai] + 
        Sin[thetai + \[Beta]]))/((\[Pi] - \[Beta]) (\[Pi] + \[Beta])) \
+ (R1^(-((2 \[Pi])/\[Beta])) R2^((3 \[Pi])/\[Beta])
       Aki[1] (Sin[thetai] + 
        Sin[thetai + \[Beta]]))/((\[Pi] - \[Beta]) (\[Pi] + \
\[Beta]))), 
 2 R2 AmI[2] CmI[2] - (2 BmI[2] CmI[2])/R2^3 == -((
   2 R1^(-((4 \[Pi])/\[Beta]))
     R2^(-1 - (
     2 \[Pi])/\[Beta]) (-R1^(((2 \[Pi])/\[Beta])) + R2^((
      2 \[Pi])/\[Beta])) \[Beta] ((R1^((2 \[Pi])/\[Beta]) + R2^((
         2 \[Pi])/\[Beta])) (\[Pi]^2 - 4 \[Beta]^2) Aki[2] Cos[
        2 thetai + \[Beta]] Sin[\[Beta]] - 
      2 R1^((2 \[Pi])/\[Beta])
        R2^(\[Pi]/\[Beta]) (\[Pi]^2 - \[Beta]^2) Aki[
        1] Cos[\[Beta]] Sin[2 thetai + \[Beta]]))/(\[Pi]^4 - 
    5 \[Pi]^2 \[Beta]^2 + 4 \[Beta]^4)), 
 AmI[1] DmI[1] - (BmI[1] DmI[1])/R2^2 == 
  R2^(-1 - (
    2 \[Pi])/\[Beta]) \[Beta] ((
     2 Aki[2] (Cos[thetai] - Cos[thetai + \[Beta]]))/(
     4 \[Pi]^2 - \[Beta]^2) + (
     4 R1^(-((4 \[Pi])/\[Beta])) R2^((4 \[Pi])/\[Beta])
       Aki[2] (-Cos[thetai] + Cos[thetai + \[Beta]]))/(
     8 \[Pi]^2 - 2 \[Beta]^2) + (
     R2^(\[Pi]/\[Beta])
       Aki[1] (Cos[thetai] + 
        Cos[thetai + \[Beta]]))/((\[Pi] - \[Beta]) (\[Pi] + \[Beta])) \
- (R1^(-((2 \[Pi])/\[Beta])) R2^((3 \[Pi])/\[Beta])
       Aki[1] (Cos[thetai] + 
        Cos[thetai + \[Beta]]))/((\[Pi] - \[Beta]) (\[Pi] + \
\[Beta]))), 
 2 R2 AmI[2] DmI[2] - (2 BmI[2] DmI[2])/R2^3 == (
  2 R1^(-((4 \[Pi])/\[Beta]))
    R2^(-1 - (
    2 \[Pi])/\[Beta]) (R1^((2 \[Pi])/\[Beta]) - R2^((
     2 \[Pi])/\[Beta])) \[Beta] (2 R1^((2 \[Pi])/\[Beta])
       R2^(\[Pi]/\[Beta]) (\[Pi]^2 - \[Beta]^2) Aki[
       1] Cos[\[Beta]] Cos[
       2 thetai + \[Beta]] + (R1^((2 \[Pi])/\[Beta]) + R2^((
        2 \[Pi])/\[Beta])) (\[Pi]^2 - 4 \[Beta]^2) Aki[
       2] Sin[\[Beta]] Sin[2 thetai + \[Beta]]))/(\[Pi]^4 - 
   5 \[Pi]^2 \[Beta]^2 + 4 \[Beta]^4), 
 Aki[1] == (1/(R2^2 (\[Pi]^4 - 5 \[Pi]^2 \[Beta]^2 + 4 \[Beta]^4)))
  2 \[Beta] (-R2 (\[Pi]^2 - 4 \[Beta]^2) (R2^2 AmI[1] + BmI[1]) Cos[
       thetai] DmI[1] - 
     R2 (\[Pi]^2 - 4 \[Beta]^2) (R2^2 AmI[1] + BmI[1]) Cos[
       thetai + \[Beta]] DmI[1] - 
     2 \[Pi]^2 R2^4 AmI[2] Cos[2 thetai] DmI[2] + 
     2 R2^4 \[Beta]^2 AmI[2] Cos[2 thetai] DmI[2] - 
     2 \[Pi]^2 BmI[2] Cos[2 thetai] DmI[2] + 
     2 \[Beta]^2 BmI[2] Cos[2 thetai] DmI[2] - 
     2 \[Pi]^2 R2^4 AmI[2] Cos[2 (thetai + \[Beta])] DmI[2] + 
     2 R2^4 \[Beta]^2 AmI[2] Cos[2 (thetai + \[Beta])] DmI[2] - 
     2 \[Pi]^2 BmI[2] Cos[2 (thetai + \[Beta])] DmI[2] + 
     2 \[Beta]^2 BmI[2] Cos[2 (thetai + \[Beta])] DmI[
       2] + \[Pi]^2 R2^3 AmI[1] CmI[1] Sin[thetai] - 
     4 R2^3 \[Beta]^2 AmI[1] CmI[1] Sin[thetai] + \[Pi]^2 R2 BmI[
       1] CmI[1] Sin[thetai] - 
     4 R2 \[Beta]^2 BmI[1] CmI[1] Sin[thetai] + 
     2 \[Pi]^2 R2^4 AmI[2] CmI[2] Sin[2 thetai] - 
     2 R2^4 \[Beta]^2 AmI[2] CmI[2] Sin[2 thetai] + 
     2 \[Pi]^2 BmI[2] CmI[2] Sin[2 thetai] - 
     2 \[Beta]^2 BmI[2] CmI[2] Sin[2 thetai] + \[Pi]^2 R2^3 AmI[
       1] CmI[1] Sin[thetai + \[Beta]] - 
     4 R2^3 \[Beta]^2 AmI[1] CmI[1] Sin[
       thetai + \[Beta]] + \[Pi]^2 R2 BmI[1] CmI[1] Sin[
       thetai + \[Beta]] - 
     4 R2 \[Beta]^2 BmI[1] CmI[1] Sin[thetai + \[Beta]] + 
     2 \[Pi]^2 R2^4 AmI[2] CmI[2] Sin[2 (thetai + \[Beta])] - 
     2 R2^4 \[Beta]^2 AmI[2] CmI[2] Sin[2 (thetai + \[Beta])] + 
     2 \[Pi]^2 BmI[2] CmI[2] Sin[2 (thetai + \[Beta])] - 
     2 \[Beta]^2 BmI[2] CmI[2] Sin[2 (thetai + \[Beta])]), 
 Aki[2] == (1/(R2^2 (4 \[Pi]^4 - 5 \[Pi]^2 \[Beta]^2 + \[Beta]^4)))
  2 \[Beta] Sin[\[Beta]/
    2] (-2 R2 (\[Pi]^2 - \[Beta]^2) (R2^2 AmI[1] + BmI[1]) CmI[1] Cos[
       thetai + \[Beta]/2] - (4 \[Pi]^2 - \[Beta]^2) (R2^4 AmI[2] + 
        BmI[2]) CmI[2] Cos[1/2 (4 thetai + \[Beta])] - 
     4 \[Pi]^2 R2^4 AmI[2] CmI[2] Cos[2 thetai + (3 \[Beta])/2] + 
     R2^4 \[Beta]^2 AmI[2] CmI[2] Cos[2 thetai + (3 \[Beta])/2] - 
     4 \[Pi]^2 BmI[2] CmI[2] Cos[
       2 thetai + (3 \[Beta])/2] + \[Beta]^2 BmI[2] CmI[2] Cos[
       2 thetai + (3 \[Beta])/2] - 
     2 \[Pi]^2 R2^3 AmI[1] DmI[1] Sin[thetai + \[Beta]/2] + 
     2 R2^3 \[Beta]^2 AmI[1] DmI[1] Sin[thetai + \[Beta]/2] - 
     2 \[Pi]^2 R2 BmI[1] DmI[1] Sin[thetai + \[Beta]/2] + 
     2 R2 \[Beta]^2 BmI[1] DmI[1] Sin[thetai + \[Beta]/2] - 
     4 \[Pi]^2 R2^4 AmI[2] DmI[2] Sin[1/2 (4 thetai + \[Beta])] + 
     R2^4 \[Beta]^2 AmI[2] DmI[2] Sin[1/2 (4 thetai + \[Beta])] - 
     4 \[Pi]^2 BmI[2] DmI[2] Sin[
       1/2 (4 thetai + \[Beta])] + \[Beta]^2 BmI[2] DmI[2] Sin[
       1/2 (4 thetai + \[Beta])] - 
     4 \[Pi]^2 R2^4 AmI[2] DmI[2] Sin[2 thetai + (3 \[Beta])/2] + 
     R2^4 \[Beta]^2 AmI[2] DmI[2] Sin[2 thetai + (3 \[Beta])/2] - 
     4 \[Pi]^2 BmI[2] DmI[2] Sin[
       2 thetai + (3 \[Beta])/2] + \[Beta]^2 BmI[2] DmI[2] Sin[
       2 thetai + (3 \[Beta])/2])}
```

First I use `Solve` and the solution is empty.

**In fact when using FindRoot I do not know the initial values, so I do not know if the initial values I have set is proper**

Then I use `FindRoot` and the tips is `FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point.......... Try perturbing the initial point(s).`
and

`FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.`

Next I have referred the post
[enter link description here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195829/findroot-jsing-encountered-a-singular-jacobian-at-a-point-why)
and it seems that the answer in that post is effective,

and changed my code as the listed forms, however the answer is not ideal, so how to solve it?

```
system = equa;
vars = {AmI[1], AmI[2], BmI[1], BmI[2], CmI[1], CmI[2], DmI[1], 
   DmI[2], Aki[1], Aki[2]};`
parameters = {u0 -> 4*\[Pi]*10^(-7), R1 -> 0.04, R2 -> 0.07, 
 R3 -> 0.08, \[Beta] -> \[Pi]/6, k1 -> 10^5, L -> 0.1, N1 -> 50, 
   K -> 50, thetai -> \[Pi]/6};

givenPoint = {{AmI[1], 0.1}, {AmI[2], 0.1}, {BmI[1], 0.1}, {BmI[2], 
0.1}, {CmI[1], 0.1}, {CmI[2], 0.1}, {DmI[1], 0.1}, {DmI[2], 
0.1}, {Aki[1], 0.1 + I}, {Aki[2], 0.1 + I}};


s5 = FindRoot[SetPrecision[system /. parameters, 24], 
 SetPrecision[givenPoint, 24], PrecisionGoal -> 8, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 24]
```

`FindRoot::precw: The precision of the argument function ....is less than WorkingPrecision.`
and

`FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point .... Try perturbing the initial point(s).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your system `equa` has no solution?

Try `NMinimize`:

```
NMinimize[{1, equa /. parameters}, vars]
(*Obtained solution does not satisfy the following constraints...*)
```

and

```
NMinimize[# . # &[equa /. Equal -> Subtract /. parameters], vars]
(*{2009.13, {AmI[1] -> -0.0644122, AmI[2] -> 0.0940232, 
BmI[1] -> 0.41307, BmI[2] -> 0.0445729, CmI[1] -> 0.048511, 
CmI[2] -> 0.0527291, DmI[1] -> -0.155755, DmI[2] -> -0.237591, 
Aki[1] -> -7.64135*10^-10, Aki[2] -> -1.55336*10^-18}}*)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have decreased the equations and variables and want the analysis more. [link]https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270410/nonlinear-equations-cannot-get-the-solution

Answer (score 3):

To support @Ulrich's answer, `Solve` indicates there is no solution:

```
Solve[system /. parameters, vars]
(*  {}  *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have decreased the equations and variables and want the analysis more. [link]https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270410/nonlinear-equations-cannot-get-the-solution