# NONLINEAR EQUATIONS cannot get the solution

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

I have simplified the equations and decrease the variables to 5, and changed the parameters' value as I think the equations in [enter link description here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270375/findrootjsing-encountered-a-singular-jacobian-at-the-point-when-solving-nonli) is because of the improper parameters' value.

and new codes are as this:

```
equa={(AmI[1] - BmI[1]/R3^2) CmI[1] == k1 u0, 
 R3 AmI[1] DmI[1] == (BmI[1] DmI[1])/R3, 
 (AmI[1] - BmI[1]/R2^2) CmI[1] == (R1^(-((2 π)/β))
    R2^(-((π + β)/β)) (R1^((2 π)/β) - R2^((2 π)/β)) β Aki[1]* 
    (Sin[thetai] + Sin[thetai + β]))/(-π^2 + β^2), 
 (AmI[1] - BmI[1]/R2^2) DmI[1] == (R1^(-((2 π)/β))
    R2^(-((π + β)/β)) (R1^((2 π)/β) - R2^((2 π)/β)) β Aki[1]* 
    (Cos[thetai] + Cos[thetai + β]))/(π^2 - β^2), 
 Aki[1] == -((2 β (R2^2 AmI[1] + BmI[1]) ((Cos[thetai] + Cos[thetai + β]) DmI[1] - 
      CmI[1] (Sin[thetai] + Sin[thetai + β])))/(R2 (π - β) (π + β)))}

system = equa;

vars = {AmI[1], BmI[1], CmI[1], DmI[1], Aki[1]};
parameters = {u0 -> 4*π*10^(-7), R1 -> 4/100, R2 -> 7/100, 
  R3 -> 8/100, β -> π/4, k1 -> (11/10)^5, L -> 0.1, 
  N1 -> 50, K -> 50, thetai -> π/6};
givenPoint = {{AmI[1], 0.1}, {BmI[1], 0.1}, {CmI[1], 0.1}, 
  {DmI[1], 0.1}, {Aki[1], 0.1 + I}};

NMinimize[# . # &[equa /. Equal -> Subtract /. parameters], vars]
```

`{1.53176*10^-12, {AmI[1] -> -1.75396*10^-6,  BmI[1] -> 8.53681*10^-9, CmI[1] -> -0.410309, DmI[1] -> 0.317123,  Aki[1] -> 2.23402*10^-13}}`

And it seems that the object is approximate to 0, however it is not 0, so I cannot get the solution by `Solve`.

**The most important question is how to analyze this nonlinear equations mathematically with 5 variables? For example using `MatrixRank` or other functions to make sure in which condition the equations will and will not have solution.**

**I do not know if it is effective to use `MatrixRank` for nonlinear equations.**

**By the way, I do not know which of vars should be real and which complex and maybe the initial values are improper.**

Comment: From your 2nd equation `AmI==BmI/R3^2` With that your 1st equation is `0==k1*u0==(11/10)^5*4*π*10^(-7)` and that is `False`

Comment: Do you know which of `vars` should be real and which  complex?

Comment: So `MatrixRank` is not useful for nonlinear equations, but your system is polynomial, and one can use `GroebnerBasis` to conclusively check if there are (complex) solutions. You can use a generic command such as `Solve` and `Reduce` but then it may be less clear what they do in the background. But `GroebnerBasis` has a clear definition. See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroebnerBasis.html) for examples, in particular under "Scope" the example "no common roots". See also [weak Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz).

Comment: @Bill The 2nd equation can alternatively be satisfied by `DmI == 0`. The whole system may still not have a solution, I have not checked.

Comment: Thanks @user293787 If `DmI==0` and thus the second equation is `True` then `Simplify` shows the 4th equation is `Aki==0` and the system is again `False`

Comment: @Bill,Thanks for your comments and surely even if `DmI[1]` is equal to 0 and `Aki[1]` is equal to 0, there is still one equation that cannot satisfy.

Comment: **I am sorry that I do not know how to reply to each one's comment below his/her comment respectively, and it seems that the `@` is not very useful, so I thank you all for all your suggestion.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Reduce` to analyze the nonlinear equations:

```
Reduce[equa /. parameters, vars]
(* False*)
```

The result confirms @Bill's helpful comment!

Answer (score 0):

1, Surely even if `DmI[1]=0` and `Aki[1]=0`, there is still one
equation that cannot satisfy.

2, I have tried to change the first 2 equations,

```
 (AmI[1] - BmI[1]/R3^2) CmI[1] == k1 u0,    
          R3 AmI[1] DmI[1] - (BmI[1] DmI[1])/R3==0,
```

Even make `k1 u0=0` and therefore the first 2 eqautions are equal to
0 respectively, there is no solution.

3, Changing the first 2 eqautions to

```
(AmI[1] - BmI[1]/R3^2) CmI[1] == C1, 
          R3 AmI[1] DmI[1] - (BmI[1] DmI[1])/R3==C2,
```

and `C1`is not equal to 0, `C2`is not equal to 0, there is still no solution.